# Why are there disproportionate deaths from new York to Washington?

Tags: virus

Regarding the corona virus, why are there many deaths in Washington but none in new York?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?

Comment: I haven't done any research, my wife said she noticed the discrepancy so i asked about it on here.

Comment: I'll leave the question open since it has an upvoted answer, but in the future be aware that questions on this site require some degree of prior research. [See this meta discussion](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Most of the COVID-19 deaths in Washington [involve a single nursing home](https://www.bellevuereporter.com/news/life-care-center-of-kirkland-breaks-silence-at-saturday-press-conference/), where the virus spread widely before being detected.

The patients at that facility are in a high-risk category for this disease due to their advanced age; there is no similar cluster of cases at a nursing facility elsewhere in the US, therefore it is not surprising that the mortality rate is quite different so far.

There is speculation that there are far more [undiagnosed cases in Washington](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/show/why-washington-health-officials-fear-novel-coronavirus-may-have-been-quietly-spreading), many of which would be mild cases. Given issues and limitations with testing, it is difficult to know what the true rate is.